# Site to ask question related to the origin of the scientific words

Tags: support, site-recommendation

When I come across some scientific terms/words in Physics, Chemistry and Mathematics (e.g., In Physics: dia, para, ferro magnetism), I try to understand the word origin. Which SE site would be appropriate to ask these kind of questions? Is it appropriate to ask Physics-related scientific word in Physics SE? While words of scientific origin come from non-English origin (e.g., Greek) also, is it appropriate these kind of questions in English-language related SE sites?

Comment: In addition to the sites you've mentioned, Hostory of Science & Mathematics may be worth to have a look at.

Comment: Chemistry mod here. [We certainly do take etymology questions.](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/search?q=etymology+is%3Aquestion) But as with all questions, please use your judgment and don't post something trivial. A recent question on cummingtonite managed to get downvoted heavily (now deleted). If the etymology can be found on Wikipedia, then it probably won't be too well-received.

Comment: Extending the previous comments: there words have mainly latinic origin, and there is also a https://latin.stackexchange.com .